# Hidden type input values not being passed in php

Tags: php, forms

I have a contact form that does a very simple captcha system such as "Is the sun hot or cold?" And the user enters hot. I include the original question and answer to the following processing form in type="hidden" fields.

The problem is that these input fields are always blank on the following php page. Here is my code on the contact form:

```
<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="POST" onsubmit="return true;" action="submit.php">
    <fieldset>
        [...]Removed For Convenience[...]
        <label class="captcha" id="captcha" name="captcha">
            <span style="color:#FFFFFF">Is the sun hot or cold?</span>
            <input type="text" value="hot" name="answer" id="answer">
            <input type="hidden" value="Is the sun hot or cold?" name="realquestion" id="realquestion">
                <input type="hidden" value="hot" name="realanswer" id="realanswer">
            <p>Please answer as simply as possible; hot, cold, z, etc. (This question is for security purposes)</p>
        </label><br>
    <div class="clear-form"></div>
        <div class="buttons-wrapper">
            <input id="button-2" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And the following page, submit.php I put this at the very top "print_r($_POST);" and this is the array that was returned:

```
Array ( [Name] => asasasas [Email] => My.Email@gmail.com [contactTime] => Best Time To Contact You? [Phone] => Phone: [Account] => Account: [OS] => [Department] => [Message] => Message: [answer] => hot [realquestion] => [realanswer] => )
```

Now the kicker, if on my contact page I change type="hidden" to type="text" for these two fields and nothing else the code will work. Once that has been done I can change it back to type="hidden" and it will continue working for that session. If I switch browsers, restart the browser, or go to a different computer it will go back to not being able to read those hidden input fields.

Has anyone come across this before or know what might be happening? I'm at a loss. I would really like to figure out this problem and not use a workaround like javascript validation, I am already doing that but I want the php check in place in case they have javascript off (I am assuming the bot spam we have been getting has it off).

Comment: Sorry, I [cannot reproduce the problem](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/cpq-31u). What does `validateForm()` do?

Comment: Checks for empty/default fields for name and email address, and does not interact with realanswer or realquestion fields at all. Since the behavior is the same with "return true;" in there I made that change in my main post.

Comment: I submitted the form on the page you provided and this was included in the output: `[realquestion] => Spell the word "Oven". [realanswer] => oven`.

Comment: On my laptop(Firefox/IE) and a co-workers laptop(chrome) we are seeing what I described in my post.

Comment: I had a second coworker check out the form and he is seeing the same behavior as us, with those final two post variables being empty.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Problem was solved by changing

```
<input type="hidden" value="Is the sun hot or cold?" name="realquestion" id="realquestion">
            <input type="hidden" value="hot" name="realanswer" id="realanswer">
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" value="Is the sun hot or cold?" name="realquestion" id="realquestion" **/>**
            <input type="hidden" value="hot" name="realanswer" id="realanswer" **/>**
```

And not getting tripped up by browser caching.

Comment: You can also reload using ctrl-F5 (chrome) +1 for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: I'm having simliar problem, while this may have fixed it for you, do you know why it was happening?

Comment: I'm afraid not, never time to go back and investigate weird quirks it seems

Comment: Have you found any solution why this code is working?

Answer (score 0):

```
$realAns = $_POST['realanswer'];
echo ($realAns);
```

Captured the hidden field values for me.